# c# Unwanted Extra Columns in Form Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am populating a data table from a ListItemCollection and then a grid view from the data table. But I am getting an extra 10 columns that are not specified in my loops below. Example column names are _ModerationStatus, _Level, ScopeId, MetaInfo. I don't know what these columns are, they are not visible in the parent data. using .Net Framework.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"];
    string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
    using (ClientContext cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret))
    {
        Web site = cc.Web;
        List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("ListOne");

        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = 
        "<View>
        <Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>House</Value> 
        </Contains></Where></Query>" +
        "<ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name=Ref />" +
        "<FieldRef Name=Name />" +
        "</ViewFields>
        </View>";

        ListItemCollection collListItem = targetList.GetItems(query);

        cc.Load(collListItem);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var field in collListItem[0].FieldValues.Keys)
        {
            dtData.Columns.Add(field);
        }

        foreach (var item in collListItem)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtData.NewRow();
            dr["Ref"] = item["Ref"];
            dr["Name"] = item["Name"];
            dtData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dgvTest.DataSource = dtData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either turn off the `AutoGenerateColumns` property on the DataGridView, or don't add the columns manually.

When you set the `DataSource` property, and `AutoGenerateColumns` is true, the columns in your DataTable are translated into columns on the DataGridView.